# Finding $r_1,r_2,n$ which satisfy some 2 equations

Tags: number-theory

Let $r_1,r_2,n$ be positive integers with $r_1<n,r_2<n$ and $r_1\neq r_2$. Given
$$r_1^{n-r_1}=r_2^{n-r_2} \text{ and } (r_1+1)^{n-r_1}=(r_2+1)^{n-r_2}.$$
Can you find $r_1,r_2,n$ which satisfy the above 2 equations?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $r_1=1$ then $r_2=1$ and vice-versa. So, we can assume that $r_1,r_2>1$. Let's also assume that $r_1>r_2$. Taking natural logarithm of both sides of these equalities we obtain $$(n-r_1)\ln r_1=(n-r_2)\ln r_2,(n-r_1)\ln(r_1+1)=(n-r_2)\ln(r_2+1)$$ so $$\frac{\ln r_1}{\ln r_2}=\frac{n-r_2}{n-r_1}=\frac{\ln(r_1+1)}{\ln(r_2+1)}\qquad(*)$$
Let's find whether there exist numbers $x,y>1$ such that $x^c=y,(x+1)^c=y+1$ for some exponent $c>1$. According to the mean value theorem there exists $x<z<x+1$ such that $cz^{c-1}=1\Rightarrow z^{c-1}=1/c$. Since $c>1$ that means $z<1$, so such $x,y$ don't exist.

Taking $c=\frac{\ln r_1}{\ln r_2}$ we see that numbers $r_1,r_2$ such that $r_1=r_2^c,(r_2+1)=(r_2+1)^{c}$ can't exist, so $(*)$ can't be true.